# Trace minimization subject to diagonal constraints

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, convex-optimization, trace, semidefinite-programming

Problem Revisited - Edited for conciseness:

We are given two set of data points X [$p \times n$] and Y [$q \times n$]. 
Let us assume $X = \hat{X} + \tilde{X}$ and $Y = \hat{Y} + \tilde{Y}$

I am trying to minimize the following objective function for $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{\hat{X}, \hat{Y}}{\text{minimize }}
& &
  \|\hat{X}'\hat{X} - \hat{Y}'\hat{Y}\|_F^2 \\
&&  =& Tr((\hat{X}'\hat{X})^2) - 2Tr(\hat{X}'\hat{X}\hat{Y}'\hat{Y}) + Tr((\hat{Y}'\hat{Y})^2)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

subject to the constraints that under the constraints that $X\tilde{X}'=0$ and $Y\tilde{Y}'=0$, and both $\Phi = \tilde{X}\tilde{X}'$ and $\Theta = \tilde{Y}\tilde{Y}'$ are PSD and diagonal.

After expansion of the above equation and application of cauchy-schwarz inequality, the original problem is reduced to the following objective function, subject to the constraint that $\Phi$ [$p \times p$] and $\Theta$ [$q \times q$] are both diagonal matrices and PSD.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{\Phi, \Theta}{\text{minimize }}
& & f\\
& 
& \leq & 2 Tr(XX'\Phi) + Tr(\Phi^2) + 2Tr(YY'\Theta)+ Tr(\Theta^2) \\
&&+& 2Tr(XX')Tr(\Theta) + 2 tr(YY')Tr(\Phi) + 2Tr(\Theta)Tr(\Phi) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \Phi \text{ and } \Theta \text{ are diagonal and PSD}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

1) Does this equation have a unique solution? If so, how can I find the solution? If not, what are the solution concepts, say w.r.t. minimization of different norms?

2) When I try to encode the problem in terms of the sum of the diagonal elements of $\Phi$ and $\Theta$, the problem is reduced to a convex quadratic program. But what does knowing about the sum of diagonal elements tell about the actual matrix itself, even if we have some extra information about say, the rank of matrices.

Comment: Are you sure there's not a $2$ in front of $\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(\Theta\Phi)$? Because it would be convex if that were so. In fact, if that *is* the case, the objective function is just $$\|A+B+\Phi+\Theta\|_F^2-\|A+B\|_F^2$$
Since you say it's a convex quadratic program, I'm guessing that $2$ is supposed to be there.

Comment: @MichaelGrant You are absolutely right. There was a 2 missing. I have now reformulated the problem (more like fixed it). Any new insights would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Wait, that's significantly different. Why did you break the products apart?

Comment: It is entirely different. I was formulating the problem in terms of diagonal PSD matrices but I had messed it up somewhere along the way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have insights for you anymore. Why are you applying Cauchy-Schwarz here? Why not just give us the original objective $f$?

Comment: @MichaelGrant Sure. Give me a couple of minute to sketch the whole problem. To be honest, this is a bit of a sunday adventure.

Comment: Ok, this is cool, but again: *what does it look like before Cauchy-Schwarz*? I think that is making it harder not easier.

Comment: What it looks like, it seems to me, is very close to what I wrote in my very first comment, though minor adjustments are required. And that is readily solvable. Your bound, not so much.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'm thinking. Ignore your attempt to use Cauchy Schwarz. Your problem looks like this:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & \left\| (X^TX-\Phi) - (Y^TY-\Theta) \right\|_F \\
\text{subject to} & 0 \preceq \Phi \preceq X^T X \\
                  & 0 \preceq \Theta \preceq Y^T Y \\
                  & \Phi,\Theta~\text{diagonal}
\end{array}
where $\preceq$ is the generalized inequality on the semidefinite cone; for instance, $\Phi\preceq X^TX$ means that $X^TX-\Phi$ is positive semidefinite.

This is convex, and in fact a semidefinite program, and is therefore amenable to solution by any semidefinite programming solver.

EDIT: I just realized it can be simplified. Since the variables only concern the diagonal, there's no point in looking at the Frobenius norm of the entire matrix, just look at the diagonal.
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & \left\| \mathop{\textrm{diag}}(X^TX-Y^TY)-\phi+\theta \right\|_2 \\
\text{subject to} & \phi,~\theta_i \geq 0, ~ i=1,2,\dots, n \\
                  & X^T X - {\mathop{\textrm{diag}}}^{-1}(\phi) \succeq 0 \\
                  & Y^T Y - {\mathop{\textrm{diag}}}^{-1}(\theta) \succeq 0
\end{array}
Not a huge savings, but why not. Now $\phi$ and $\theta$ are just vectors.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused here. Doesn't the objective need to be linear for it to be a semidefinite program? As written it looks like there are nonlinear cusps in it. I was thinking one might squaring the objective and use an interior point method - is that not as good?

Comment: Well, I'm using the term a bit loosely, yes. A pure semidefinite solver is going to require a linear objective. This is going to require a bit of work to convert to pure semidefinite form, but a modeling framework like [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx) or YALMIP (http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/) is going to have no problem with that. Don't square the objective, that's for sure.

Comment: What CVX would do, and what I would do if I were doing it by hand, is to linearize the objective by moving the Frobenius norm to a constraint. That constraint is isomorphic to a standard SOCP constraint. Most SDP solvers can handle SOCP constraints natively.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this question. I'll go through it thoroughly tomorrow, and let you know. I really appreciate it.

Comment: This is a bit confusing, which explains my attempt to use Cauchy Schwarz inequality to establish an upper bound. This may very well be quite trivial but please help me out here. Independence of $X$ and $\tilde{X}$, that is $X\tilde{X}'=0$ does not necessarily imply that $X'\tilde{X}=0$. So is the case with the diagonal matrices.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is, say, if $\tilde{X}\tilde{X}'$ [$p\times p$] is diagonal, then $\tilde{X}'\tilde{X}$ [n \times n] is not necessarily diagonal.

Comment: I see. You are probably right. Oh well, I tried.

Comment: Thanks alot. I really appreciate it. I change the problem so it conforms to the answer you gave. I am sure there are people out there who will find this super useful!

Comment: Oh I see no need for such a change. Leave it as it is, as a record of discussion. I do have some frustration over your insistence on jumping to the Cauchy Schwarz transformation. If you want help solving the problem, ask! But don't solve it half-way and ask for someone to solve the other half. After all, what if your half is in the wrong direction?

Comment: Sure, I wont change it. I am new around here. I'll certainly take that into consideration the next time I post a question.

Comment: Actually, are you sure this can't be salvaged? After all, consider this:$$\|X^TX\|_F^2=\langle X^TX,X^TX\rangle = \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TXX^TX)=\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(XX^TXX^T)=\langle XX^T,XX^T 
\rangle=\|XX^T\|_F^2$$
I know you have a difference here but perhaps judicious use of the $\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(AB)=\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(BA)$ identity can help.

Comment: I do use the cyclic invariance of Trace, quite extensively. But still not much progress!